# Google Map rendering in Iframe

Tags: google-maps, iframe

Hi I am rendering googlemap with below code. I need to display the map below using iframe.

But passing latitude and logitude as parameters. Please let me know the way to pass latitude and logitude as parameters values instead of address as below.

```
  <iframe width="{600}" height="{500}" src="{https://maps.google.com/maps?         
  q=Berry%20Street%2012%20%2C%20%20New%20York&t=m&z=14&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed}" 
  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>

  <iframe src="http://www.embed-google-map.com/embed-map.php?get=map-datas" 
  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">

 </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the center parameter, here is the snippet you would need to add with the latitude and longitude specified.

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=API_KEY&center=40.7220423,-73.9599656&zoom=18&maptype=satellite">
</iframe>
```

### Optional parameters

**center** defines the center of the map view. It accepts a comma-separated latitude and longitude value (such as 37.4218,-122.0840).

**zoom** sets the initial zoom level of the map.

**maptype** can be either roadmap (the default) or satellite, and defines the type of map tiles to load.

**language** defines the language to use for UI elements and for the display of labels on map tiles.

**region** defines the appropriate borders and labels to display.

More info: [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#api_key)

You need an API KEY, though. Get one [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#api_key)